# What was the default color palette for images in seaborn version 0.2?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

A thing I immediately liked about [`seaborn`](http://www.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) was that it set the Matplotlib default color palette for images (`imshow`, `pcolormesh`, `contourf`, ...) to a very good one I had not seen before (black-blue-green-brown-pink-purple-white):

```
plt.contourf(np.random.random((20,20)))
```

[image: Default contourf plot under seaborn v. 0.2.1]

But when I upgraded the package from version 0.21 to 0.3, this default changed to some greyscale:

[image: Default contourf plot under seaborn v. 0.3]

What is the default color palette from v. 0.2.1 called and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default color palette in seaborn v. 0.2.1 is [Dave Green's `'cubehelix'`](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~dag/CUBEHELIX/) and you can get it back in v. 0.3 via

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'image.cmap': 'cubehelix'})
```

A 'brute force' way of finding this out is rolling back to the old version and creating a default plot:

```
img = plt.contourf(np.random.random((20,20)))
print(img.cmap.name)
```

In fact, the default in seaborn is defined in [this file in the seaborn repo](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/rcmod.py#L199). A look into the [Matplotlib sample matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) might also help to find the right parameters to adjust.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to j08lue's answer, the reason it changed is that it's pretty much impossible to choose a single default colormap that is appropriate for all kinds of data, and having a bad color map can cause [lots](http://eagereyes.org/basics/rainbow-color-map) [of](http://www.sandia.gov/~kmorel/documents/ColorMaps/ColorMapsExpanded.pdf) [problems](http://www.jwave.vt.edu/~rkriz/Projects/create_color_table/color_07.pdf). The hope it that by making the default a grayscale map, it will encourage people to think about their data and choose the right kind of map.

By the way all (most?) matplotlib functions that plot with a colormap will take a `cmap` keyword argument, i.e. `plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap="cubehelix")` will work.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, Michael, that is actually a very good initiative.

Comment: The last two links are broken.